# Show/hide radiobuttons where the determinant is date

Tags: php, radio-button

In registration Form I have selection for contest fees:

```
<p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date1" value="30"> 30€ until 30 may</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date1" value="15">child 15€ until 30 may</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date2" value="50"> 50€ until 30 june</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date2" value="25">child 25€ until 30 june</p>  
    <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date3" value="80">80€ until 10 july</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date3" value="40"> 40€ child until 10 july
```

How can I display only two first rows in form until 30 may (`class=date1`)
after that only 3-4 row from 30may to 30 june (`class=date2`)
and last two rows from 30 june to 10 july (`class=date3`)

Comment: I did not exactly got your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work based on my understanding of your problem.

```
<?php $current_time = time(); ?>
<?php if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2015)) { ?>
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date1" value="30"> 30€ until 30 may</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date1" value="15">child 15€ until 30 may</p>
<?php } else if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2015)) { ?>
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date2" value="50"> 50€ until 30 june</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date2" value="25">child 25€ until 30 june</p>
<?php } else if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 11, 2015)) { ?>  
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date3" value="80">80€ until 10 july</p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="fee" class="date3" value="40"> 40€ child until 10 july
<?php } ?>
```

Note that this seems pretty dangerous, as I could easily manipulate the request and send fee=0. Hopefully you have some error checking on the server side.

---Edit---

Make sure to disallow all invalid inputs when accepting input from an unknown source (ie. a user on the web). Since you have a very limited amount of valid inputs on this form, you can easily check to make sure it is one of those valid inputs.

Without checking like this, someone could alter their request and sent fee=1. They could then possibly get a ticket for 1€. Although you may have other processes in place to prevent that.

```
$current_time = time();
if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 1, 2015)) {
  if ($_POST['fee'] !== '15' && $_POST['fee'] !== '30') {
    // return error
  }
} else if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2015)) {
  if ($_POST['fee'] !== '25' && $_POST['fee'] !== '50') {
    // return error
  }
} else if ($current_time < mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 11, 2015)) { 
  if ($_POST['fee'] !== '40' && $_POST['fee'] !== '80') {
    // return error
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's @Tyler Marien this is what I looking for and works for me. And Yes I have checking something like that 'if(empty($_POST['fee'])){ // Adds name to array $data_missing[] = 'fee';' or what you had in mind?

Comment: I added some error checking code to my answer. Obviously I know nothing of the entire ticket buying process, so this may already be handled in non-programmatic ways (ie. someone has to review the submission before sending tickets, etc).

Comment: Thanks again @Tyler Marien You helped me a lot.